# Python 3 Flask HTTPS server

Tags: python, encryption, heroku, flask, openssl

I'm running Python3.4 with flask 0.10.1 and I'm trying to implement HTTPS so that my login pages etc are encrypted.

My book on Flask Web Development suggests that SSLify will do what I want but all that happens is that I get BAD requests with a load of encrypted data in the header and there is no way to specify the SSL encryption keys it seems other than to use heroku which I don't think is an option if I have understood what it is correctly because my server will run on a network with no internet access and heroku is an internet cloud service. Looking at the SSLify documentation it does not mention anything about needing a cloud service for it to work only that 4 lines of code and you have a working HTTPS server. So I'm clearly not understanding something there or the documentation assumes the reader is a web GURU which obviously I'm not. :-)

So I then took a look at pyOpenSSL to load the keys and create a context but it hangs forever on the line:

```
    context.use_privatekey_file(os.path.join(basedir, 'certs\\server.key'))
```

Now my key file is encrypted with a password so I have no idea how everyone else is doing this when I see other posts on the internet as I cannot find out how to tell OpenSSL what the password is when specifying the key file?????

I think I'm completely barking up the wrong tree here so can anyone out there point me in the right direction please?